# How can I create virtual environment for non-python stuffs?

Tags: virtualenv

Python Virtual environment has helped me in dealing with multiple versions of same python softwares without messing up my system(I use python tool labelme in a virtualenv which i couldnot install due to some dependency problem in my host system). Is there any similar thing which I can use to install multiple versions of software(say different versions of Java) and play with them without affecting my beloved system and pushing it into software conflicts? Or can I use python virtual env for this purpose?

Comment: No you can't use python virtual env. That's specific to python. Another option is container technology such as [docker](https://www.docker.com/).

Comment: It's more to manage but you can also use virtual machines.

Comment: But virtual machine will use a lot system resources unlike python virtual env, which simply modifies some path and system variables to create a new env. @Nasir Riley

Comment: @AbinashDash I've already stated that. I was just mentioning it as another option. Either way, a virtual environment isn't going to work for what you want to do.

Comment: After searching for containers, I tried LXC and it gave me what I wanted. Wating for a good answer . Else I will write it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LXC gave me what I wanted. I installed it using `sudo apt install lxc` and set it up properly using [official ubuntu guide  for LXC](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/lxc.html). I'm using the container without root privilege. The container can be created with root privilege also(check the guide). But I didn't need it so i proceeded with the non-priviledged one.